# Compare current date to a dates in the database to see if the dates expired and change another sql value with this

Tags: php, sql

In php I am looking to compare the current date with dates in my database and if the current date is past any stored date I want to change another sql field to expired. Would you have any idea how to go about that.

Thanks

Comment: mention your inputs?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post and add representative rows of your database (as text) and your expected result so we can know how to best answer your question?

Comment: Your question is too broad in its current form. Please read [ask] and [mcve] and then [edit] your question appropriately.

Comment: Also, consider not adding business logic to your database if the result can be easily retrieved from the database. In your case, you could select the projection of the dates to the "expired" flag in your `select` query: `select case when join_date + '2 weeks' < now and last_pay_date + '30 days' < now then 'Y' else 'N' end as expired, ...`

Answer (score 0):

i think you are trying to solve is this

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$sql = "SELECT id from table_name where date_column = $today";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
  while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
     $id = $res['id'];
     $qry = mysql_query("update table_name set column_name='Expired' where id='$id'");
     if($qry){
       echo "updated";
     }

  }
}
```

i hope it will fulfill your needs.. good luck